# Is there any way to have espresso ViewAssert for regular expressions?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-automation

I would like to know if is there any way to generate espresso ViewAssert for regular expressions, something like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.element_id)).check(matches(withRegEx("\\+d")));
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Match text on a view?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to look for a matcher that already exists within espresso, but also didn't find one. A suggestion is to create your own. Here's an example using kotlin:

```
class RegexMatcher(private val regex: String) : BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView::class.java) {
    private val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("Checking the matcher on received view: with pattern=$regex")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: TextView?) =
        item?.text?.let {
            pattern.matcher(it).matches()
        } ?: false
}
```

This defines a matcher that will check `TextView`s for their text matching a specific regex pattern.

You can have this little factory function:

```
 private fun withPattern(regex: String): Matcher<in View>? = RegexMatcher(regex)
```

And then you can use it like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.element_id)).check(matches(withPattern("\\+d")))
```

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing. The above worked perfectly for me.